# Adding the same elements to different rows - @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, psql

I created a simple `Task` class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Employee assignee;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> precedingTasks;

    // ...something more
}
```

I would like to add the same `precedingTasks` to different rows of table `Task`, for example (number mean **Id**):

`/task/3` have `precedingTasks`: 1, 2

`/task/2` have `precedingTasks`: 1

`/task/4` have `precedingTasks`: 2, 3

But I get the error:
`BŁĄD: podwójna wartość klucza narusza ograniczenie unikalności` which means in English translation: `ERROR: the double key value violates the uniqueness constraint`

**Does exist any way to use "the same" preceding tasks in different tasks?**

Comment: How can you have a List with the same element with multiple owners? You simply have a FK in the element, which can point to one owner only! Use a JOIN TABLE for the relation and you can do that

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks ;)  I miss this.

Comment: @lord_hokage Billy's solution worked :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do 'itself to itself relationship' you should add `@ManyToOne` annotation as fk constraint, and mapped it by object name.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Task task;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
private List<Task> tasks;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to do this tommorow and I will let you know if it help ;)